# Reading a hard drive low level byte by byte

Tags: vb6, io

I could read the bytes of a file by opening it for binary and then using the "Get" statement.
does anyone know of any such method to do the same for reading of a whole drive?

Comment: unless u know a lot about filesystems this will give you uncomprehensible garbage and if you try to modify it you will probably get into a lot of trouble (+reformat ?)

Comment: @Joe Winfield, Do you want this to access locked files in low level?

Answer (score 1):

`fopen("/dev/sda","r")`

A little trickier on windows

```
// note need share write for NTFS even for read only`
HANDLE hRaw = CreateFile("\\\\.\\C:",GENERIC_READ,
                    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                    NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);
```

But since it isn't going to do you any good without some serious knowledge of NTFS internals that doesn't really matter.

Comment: why isn't it going to do me any good? i am not sure what you think i plan to do. i just want to read the drive byte by byte. i have read the documentation on fopen()...even if it would do it i am not sure how efficient that method would be.

Comment: If you just want to copy the data this is fine (if a little slow), if you want to read data you will have to understand the filesystem in order to discover which blocks go with which file, if you want to modify data you will have to really understand the filesystem to update all the checksums and file tables

Comment: the win32 api has CreateFile. thedocumantation says "Creates or opens a file or I/O device. The most commonly used I/O devices are as follows: file, file stream, directory, physical disk, volume, console buffer, tape drive, communications resource, mailslot, and pipe. The function returns a handle that can be used to access the file or device for various types of I/O depending on the file or device and the flags and attributes specified."  If this is what fopen does then i might definitely be well on my way with that one.